# How to use Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExtractLanguageName?

Tags: sitecore-api

There is a method called `ExtractLanguageName(string localPath)` in `WebUtil`, which is suppoed to extract the language from the request url (I think).

But what value for "localPath" does this method expect?

If the request url is something like `http://mysite/fr-ca?search=true` then the Request I get has values:

```
FilePath = "/"  
RawUrl = "/fr-ca?search=true"
```

(To tell the truth I don't understand why FilePath isn't `/fr-ca` ?)

Neither of those strings results in a "correct" return value from ExtractLanguageName.

Is something else going on? Why is FilePath simply "/".

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

`ExtractLanguageName` will do this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(localPath) || !localPath.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
   return (string) null;
int num = localPath.IndexOfAny(new char[2]{ '/', '.' }, 1);
if (num < 0)
    num = localPath.Length;
return localPath.Substring(1, num - 1);
```

So you need a value that includes your full path - but not the querystring.

Comment: Yes thanks. I am beginning to suspect that something else is going on in my application before it reaches the point where I want to extract the language from the url.  
I do not understand why my FilePath is "/" instead of "/fr-ca" (or "/fr-ca/").  
Obviously I can't use the FilePath or the RawUrl which I have available, so I'll probably just write my own language-extraction method specific to my circumstances.  
In fact, just adding a "?" to the IndexOfAny call, and using the RawUrl, will work for me.

Comment: The `StripLanguageProcessor` in the pipeline will remove /fr-ca from the url.